# OpenVAS using though terminal

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, network-security, openvas

I want to use openVAS through terminal not on to browser. So is it possible ?? for scanning, for scheduled a new scan.

I am already using openVAS but on to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible and pretty easy with the XML format they provide. Have a look here for the command syntax http://www.openvas.org/omp-6-0.html . You can set up scheduled scans as well to kick off whenever you want. Good luck